# Updating SQL Server database table every second

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a C# application that receives some data (about 700 values) per second.

I need to update these all values in a column of a database table (about 700 rows) every second.

Is it possible in this time slot? What will be the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Possible. You will have to change few default settings namely, total transaction threshold and user transaction threshold.

Check this out for more details.

1. [Microsoft SQL Server Transactions Per Second too high indication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITMD/SC23-4852-00/en_US/HTML/mssql511rg93.htm)
2. [DBA: Very high transactions per second](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/very-high-transactions-per-second)
3. [SQL Server memory performance metrics : Part 5](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-5-understanding-lazy-writes-free-list-stallssec-memory-grants-pending/)

Also, this question is more suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ Please do check this SO website.

Comment: I tried to achieve this by simply using "Command.ExecuteNonQuery()" but it is taking too long almost 20 seconds. Tried also to do with Transaction but no gain!

Comment: What are your server specs? allocating 2GB RAM and expecting it to work like that is impossible.

Comment: 4GB RAM Corei5 2.8GHz
What should be the minimum specs for my task?

Comment: It might be not sufficient. I've modified my answer and added one more link to check your server performance. Also, did you change user threshold?

Comment: What's your code to insert look like? How many records are there in the table already? do you have a primary key? Is it definitely the database insert part that is the hold up in your code? Use Activity Monitor or `sp_who2` or `sp_WhoIsActive` to see if the hold up is in the database.